# Remove the hash fragment from url permanently

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I use oauth authentication to login user. After the user has  logged in, get taken from URL. URL like this: http://xxx/callback#access_token=xxx. then redirect to other page. I use ***this.router.navigateByUrl*** to redirect, the hash tag is removed but when I click other link,the hash fragment will show again. How can I remove the hash token fragment permanently?

Example:

after use login in ***//xxx/callback#access_token=xxx***

redirect to ***//xxx/home***

then click linkA, the url is ***//xxx/linkA#access_token=xxx***

expected url is ***//xxx/linkA***

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this has been fixed in the Angular 2 final release (testing it with 2.1.0 right now).

The following works for me:

```
router.navigate([]);
```

Redirects to the "index" page without the hash and it doesn't reappear on subsequent navigation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how you redirect but I assume it's caused by the method you use.

One way to reset the fragment is

```
<a routerLink="path" fragment="">
```

(not tested myself yet).

From code

```
let tree = this.router.navigate(['path'], {relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: ''});
```

See also https://angular.io/api/router/Router#createurltree

Comment: Thanks, just after login redirect, the first url is a OAuth callback url. I redirect by code not by html tag

Comment: this works ,<a routerLink="path" [fragment]="['']" /> . but still have the tag #,like http://xxx/x#

Comment: Sorry, I somehow mixed it with query parameters. Have you tried `[fragment]="[]"`?

Comment: [fragment]="[]" is the same as [fragment]="['']", you are right. Do you know how can remove the fragment in the router without redirecting and navigating? Is there a method?

Comment: I guess not. . . .

Comment: How specify a route that navigate to it without hash, how remove the pattern hashlocationstrategy for only route

Answer (score 3):

You should put `useHash` equal to `false` at the imports of your app.module

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [App],
  imports: [
    ....
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false })
  ],
  providers: []
})
```

putting it to false will stop it from using `HashLocationStrategy` which is the default in `RouterModule.forRoot function`

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue, my solution is after retrieved access_token, you can set:
window.location.hash = ''

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are for example using auth0 in their doc they do :

```
this.auth0.parseHash({ _idTokenVerification: false }, (err, authResult) => {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
      window.location.hash = "";
    } 
});
```

Instead  do:

```
this.auth0.parseHash({ _idTokenVerification: false }, (err, authResult) => {
    if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
      this.router.navigate["/home"]
    } 
});
```

This will remove the whole hash