# window.open(url) mailto adds a hashtag to end of my url. How do I stop it from doing that or forward my url/# to my url/?

Tags: javascript, mailto

Here is the simple function that gets called when a button is clicked:

```
// Contact form
function sendEmail(){
  var name = document.getElementById("nameField").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("emailField").value;
  var subject = document.getElementById("subjectField").value;
  var message = document.getElementById("messageField").value;

  if(name != "" && email != "" && subject != "" && message != ""){
    var url = 'mailto:email@emailprovider.com?subject=' + name + ' (' + email + ')' + ' ' + subject + '&body=' + message;
    window.location.href = url;
  } else {
    console.log("SOMETHING WAS EMPTY");
  }

};
```

But then it keeps redirecting me to http://127.0.0.1:5500/# instead of http://127.0.0.1:5500/ How do I prevent this?

Comment: You are using some front end Framework?

Comment: For angular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41236150/12826802

Comment: No I am using strictly html/sass/javascript

Comment: What server is serving localhost:5500?

Comment: I'm using the Live Host plugin for visual studio

Comment: I've tried publishing it to my github pages account and it does the same thing.

Comment: Any other packages or libraries?

Comment: Nope. Just pure javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. I had action=“#” in the form html. I will mark this as answered.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
// Contact form
function sendEmail() {

  const name = document.getElementById("nameField").value;
  const email = document.getElementById("emailField").value;
  const subject = document.getElementById("subjectField").value;
  const message = document.getElementById("messageField").value;

  if (name && email && subject && message) {

        let url = window.location.origin;
        let params = 'mailto:email@emailprovider.com?subject=' + name + ' (' + email + ')' + ' ' + subject + '&body=' + message;

        window.location.href = url + params;

  } else {
    console.error("SOMETHING WAS EMPTY");
  }
};
```

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. It is still forwarding me to 127.0.0.1:5500/#